# In wininet.h what is SECURITY_SET_MASK intended to be used for?

Tags: windows, winapi, wininet

In wininet.h what is SECURITY_SET_MASK intended to be used for? I can't find any documentation for it online.

Comment: look for [`Option Flags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384066(v=vs.85).aspx) for `WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [*mask*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)), allowing you to set or clear multiple bits (flags) at once. In this case, it's all of the settable security flags.

The definition of this constant in the SDK headers is the authoritative reference for precisely which flags are included in the mask:

```
#define SECURITY_SET_MASK (SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION        | 
                           SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA        |
                           SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID   |
                           SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID |
                           SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_WRONG_USAGE)
```

Each of those flags will, of course, have its own [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328.aspx).

Comment: Also note the file comment in *wininet.h*: `// setable flags`. In other words, the mask filters out *"setable flags"* (vs. flags that are valid for queries only).

Comment: I've been reading the documentation and the header.  I'm just trying to understand the context in which this would be used.  Presumably setting those flags basically disables all the SSL security features...which seems like a strange thing to have a shorthand for :)

Comment: @JCx: You don't use this constant as an argument directly. You are using it to mask out the bits that are setable. This is done when you need to separate the setable flags from other flags, when you have a single flags value.

Comment: I'm just looking at someones code which reads as follows:         dwFlags |= SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA | SECURITY_SET_MASK;
        InternetSetOption (request, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &dwFlags, sizeof (dwFlags));
Doesn't look too healthy to me...

Comment: @JCx: A constant that acts as a mask should never be used with a binary OR (`|`) operator. That simply doesn't make sense. It should be used with binary AND (`&`) only. The expression `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA | SECURITY_SET_MASK` is identical to `SECURITY_SET_MASK`, so why even OR something to it. Without additional context, this should be discarded as *"unintentional"*.

Comment: Thanks - it looked wrong, but I thought I'd better check I wasn't being stupid.  I've discussed it with the people who wrote the library.  They are taking it out thank god ;-)